# Usage of Pick in JHipster client entities

Tags: typescript, jhipster

I'm trying to understand the usage of Pick/Omit in generated client entities in JHipster. For instance, I have this generated:

```
export interface IHouse {
  id: number;
  creationDate?: dayjs.Dayjs | null;
  room?: Pick<IRoom, 'id'> | null;
}
```

And IRoom looks like this:

```
export interface IRoom{
  id: number;
  code?: string | null;
}
```

I need to display room's code from house instance, but I can't because of this Pick structure. I don't understand the value of this utility type here. Can someone enlight me on this please?

Comment: Please consider adding the `typescript` tag. This will help StackOverflow better sort the question and will add syntax highlighting to your question.

Comment: @mshima's answer is correct, you should accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)<IRoom, 'id'> removes every property from IRoom type except the 'id'.

Others fields are not used, so they are irrelevant to relationships and omitted. This matches the backend with DTO behavior passing only the id and the label field.

If you customized the ui with the code field, just customize the type by adding `code` to the Pick fields like:

```
export interface IHouse {
  id: number;
  creationDate?: dayjs.Dayjs | null;
  room?: Pick<IRoom, 'id', 'code'> | null;
}
```

Or remove the Pick:

```
export interface IHouse {
  id: number;
  creationDate?: dayjs.Dayjs | null;
  room?: IRoom | null;
}
```

#### Missing label field

The example jdl is:

```
entity Room {
  code String
}

entity House {
  creationDate Date
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  House to Room
}
```

Adding a label to the relationship will generate like you want:

```
relationship ManyToOne {
  House{room(code)} to Room
}
```

Result:

```
export interface IHouse {
  id: number;
  creationDate?: dayjs.Dayjs | null;
  room?: Pick<IRoom, 'id', 'code'> | null;
}
```

#### Rest api without DTO

Given the jdl:

```
entity Room {
  code String
}

entity House {
  creationDate Date
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  House{room} Room{house}
}
```

Serializing the an entity would generate a circular exception due to the bi-directional relationship.

To avoid the circular exception, the backend is generated ignoring relationships like:

```
class House {
  JsonIgnoreProperties({'house', ...others relationships})
  Room room;
}
```

In typescript:

```
type House {
  room?: Omit<Room, 'house', ...others relationships>
}
```

Only the label field is relevant to the generated ui, we are using the `Pick` approach to keep templates simpler.

This can be easily customized using local blueprint.

Comment: FYI, i'm not using DTOs. Also once House is fetched from back-end, room's info is there as a whole, so why remove it? Or maybe it's only relevant when using DTOs?

Comment: Or maybe it's only relevant when using DTOs? No, non-DTOs still removes relationships in the backend, so the alternative would generate more noise by using Omit like: `Omit<entity, 'relationship1', 'relationship2', ...>`

Comment: Sorry not sure I follow, what do you mean by: `Pick<IRoom, 'id'> removes every property from IRoom type except the 'id'. Others fields are not used, so they are irrelevant to relationships and omitted` All relationships of House are fetched eagerly, therefore infos like room are available in the REST body and can be used, hence my question why having a Pick instead of Room, am I missing something? So far, i've opted for your second option, but I'll have to modify all other TS entities.